# Connection to Database Error

Tags: database, jdbc

I am using Oracle Express Edition to work with a project. I have the following code to connect to my database:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:driver_type:[username/password]@//host_name:port_number:SID");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from [Sheet1$]");

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();


        while (rs.next()) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                if (i > 1)
                    System.out.print(", ");
                String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                System.out.print(columnValue);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        st.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.print("Exception: ");
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }



}
```

When I try to run it, I get a failed to call database error, Missing in or out parameter at index 1. What is wrong with my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you got the oracle driver (`Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");`)? does [this help](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC)

Comment: I tried, but I still get the error. I am using a thin driver.

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but I think that the connection string has `//` missing: `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc://oracle:driver_type:[username/password]@//host_name:port_number:SID");` (Just to discard the obvious)

Comment: @Barranka, I just tried that, but I still get the error.

Comment: Maybe try with the oci driver.  are you developing for applet or desktop?